# Как установить высоту QTextEdit

Tags: python, qt5, pyqt5

Как увеличить высоту ячейки компонента `QTextEdit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1 вариант

Связать `QTextEdit` с [`QVBoxLayout`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvboxlayout.html) тогда он растянется на всю ширину `QVBoxLayout`. Пример:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import sys


class Main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('TextEdit')
        self.resize(400, 400)
        self.setFont(QFont('Times', 13))
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        text_edit = QTextEdit(self)
        layout.addWidget(text_edit)
        self.setLayout(layout)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Main()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

## 2 вариант

Для `QTextEdit` прописывать размер [`resize(x, y)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#resize-1).  Пример:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import sys


class Main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('TextEdit')
        self.resize(400, 400)
        self.setFont(QFont('Times', 13))
        text_edit = QTextEdit(self)
        text_edit.resize(200, 50)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Main()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

Так же можно использовать [`setFixedSize(x, y)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setFixedSize-1) вместе с `QVBoxLayout`. Пример:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import sys


class Main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('TextEdit')
        self.resize(400, 400)
        self.setFont(QFont('Times', 13))
        text_edit = QTextEdit(self)
        text_edit.setFixedSize(200, 50)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(text_edit)
        self.setLayout(layout)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Main()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Большое спасибо